# Install Adwaita shell theme in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: themes, gnome-shell

I would like to install the default GNOME 3 shell theme (the one used in Fedora for example), but I can't seem to find it anywhere (it's not even on gnome-look).

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this? The only way I can think of is to use the `gnome-session` package, but that seems quite overkill frankly.

To clarify, I'm looking for the shell theme, not the GTK theme (I have the User Themes extension installed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a folder "myShellTheme" or any name as you wish in `/usr/share/themes/`
2. Create subfolder in "myShellTheme" named "gnome-shell"

   [image]
3. Copy the required theme file

   ```
   sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css /usr/share/themes/myShellTheme/gnome-shell/
   ```

   [image]
4. Close all the files, Open Gnome-Tweaks and Select "myShellTheme" under User Themes

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can load the vanilla GNOME shell theme (Adwaita) from your home directory. To do that follow the steps below.

1. Create a directory, say `MyTheme` either in `~/.themes` or in `~/.local/share/themes`. (You may create `~/.themes` or `~/.local/share/themes` if they don't exist.)
2. Create another directory inside `MyTheme` called `gnome-shell`.
3. Create an empty text file in this `gnome-shell` directory and name it `gnome-shell.css`.
4. Open this `gnome-shell.css` in a text editor and add the following line

   ```
   @import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css");
   ```

   Then save the file.
5. Launch *(GNOME) Tweaks*, go to **Appearance** section, and click the drop-down box next to "*Shell*" theme. **MyTheme** should appear in the drop-down list (assuming you've the '[User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/)' extension installed and enabled). Select it.
   (You may have to re-login or restart GNOME shell to see the effect)