# Ubuntu 19.10 current app icons grayed out

Tags: icons, 19.10

On my fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10 dual-booted with Windows 10 Pro, the bar at the top of my screen that shows what program is open is grayed out. It still works but the app icon is gray. Can someone please help me with this issue?

[image: Screenshot of Opera icon grayed out]

Comment: Oh. Can I not make it use the normal colors?

Comment: @UbuntuUser0669 how did you install 0pera? snap or apt?? Based on that I may trY

Comment: I don't think it's an issue. It's the normal behavior

Answer (score 0):

***Workaround***

It is possible for all the app-icons. It is dependent on the "gnome-shell" theme you are using.

for the default installation of Ubuntu 19.10, below is the file.
`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css`

There are lot of posts how to edit the theme files locally instead of changing the above file directly. for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1106547/739431

Below is the code from the original file..

```
#panel .panel-button .app-menu-icon {
  -st-icon-style: symbolic;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px; }
```

I have changed it to

```
#panel .panel-button .app-menu-icon {
  -st-icon-style: none;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px; }
```

[image]

[image]