# Install Adwaita shell theme on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I know this question is already asked but was for Ubuntu 18.10.

I have found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106349/install-adwaita-shell-theme-in-ubuntu-18-10) but when i tried to find `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`i didn't find anything. so this method is no longer working on the last version of ubuntu.

I am wondering how to install stock Adwaita shell theme on Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36?

edit : i have found the solution by extracting `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` using this [script](https://github.com/devpytech/scripts/tree/master/gresource-extract) i got gnome-shell.css file which i moved to `/usr/share/themes/AnyNameOfYourChoice/gnome-shell/`  then changing shell theme using gnome-tweaks

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have `gnome-session` package installed as I am using stock GNOME on 20.04.
It has been changed to `gnome-shell-theme.gresource`. Located in `/usr/share/gnome-shell`.

I managed to extract `gresource` by running

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell

gresource extract gnome-shell-theme.gresource /org/gnome/shell/theme/gnome-shell.css > ~/gnome-shell.css

sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/themes/new-theme/gnome-shell

sudo cp ~/gnome-shell.css /usr/share/themes/new-theme/gnome-shell
```

Make sure [users themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extension is enabled. Now it should appear in GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: i dont want to install gnome-session package, if there is any solution to install only Adwaita shell theme it will be nice.

Comment: I edited my answer with the solution I found should it be helpful

Comment: Another supported location is `~/.themes/${theme-name}/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`. I prefer that since it doesn't require root to modify. Had to look in the user-theme extension's [source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell-extensions/-/blob/master/extensions/user-theme/util.js#L6) to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Just install `gnome-session`:

```
sudo apt install gnome-session
```

Log out, then select *GNOME* from the bottom right icon of the login screen and then log back in your user account using your password.