# Where I find ./extract.sh

Tags: 20.04

on the question "Install Adwaita shell theme on Ubuntu 20.04 ?" there is a reference to extract a file with the script *extract.sh* .
Where do I get this script?
Thank you

Comment: This one? https://askubuntu.com/q/1231043/158442? I don't see an `extract.sh` there

Comment: Yes. The reference to the script  "extracting /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource using this script". on clicking on the word script a page opens with        extract.sh on it I need this script to following  the change the Top Bar color.

Comment: You mean [this](https://github.com/devpytech/scripts/blob/master/gresource-extract/extract.sh)? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IOo6.png

Answer (score 0):

A reference to the extract script can be found in the fourth paragraph of this question: [Install Adwaita shell theme on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1231043/).

> I have found the solution by extracting `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` using this [script](https://github.com/devpytech/scripts/tree/master/gresource-extract). I got gnome-shell.css file which I moved to `/usr/share/themes/AnyNameOfYourChoice/gnome-shell/`  then changing shell theme using gnome-tweaks.